# Model weights means in Machine Learning

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm currently learning machine learning.i get confused what is Model weights term. please explain to me what is model weight really means

Comment: weight of what?

Comment: it is Weight of model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights are the numbers you use to turn your samples into a prediction. In many (most?) cases this is what you are learning with your system. For example, suppose you want to predict house price using only the house size (x). You might use a simple linear regression model that tries to fit a line to the data. The formula you will use is the formula for a line:

```
y = w * x + b
```

Here x is given (the house size) and you use `w` and `b`  to predict `y` the price. In this case `w` and `b` are your weights. The goal is to determine which w and b give the best fit to the data.

In more complex models like neural networks (or even more complicated linear regression) you may have dramatically more weights in you model, but the basic idea of finding those weights that best fit the data is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much,now i kinda have understanding of it